# Calculating the average in single linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a linq statement that will do the following. I need to calculate the average in one linq statement. Whats the best way to do it

```
var onlyLayer0 = trigger2Output.NpvResults.CommIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0);
var numberOfRecords = onlyLayer0.Count();
var totalPremiumPaid = onlyLayer0.Sum(x => x.premPaid);
var avgpremiumPaid = totalPremiumPaid / numberOfRecords;
```

My current linq statement

```
trigger2Output.NpvResults.CommIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0)
                            .Sum(x => x.premPaid)
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with `Enumerable.Average`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `var  avgpremiumPaid = ....Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Average(x = > x.premPaid);`?

Comment: I should note also that this msdn page is first hit for "linq average".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
trigger2Output.NpvResults.CommIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Average(r => r.premPaid);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the average extension :

```
trigger2Output.NpvResults.CommIns.Where(x => x.layerId == 0).Average(x => x.premPaid)
```

Here the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.